# SQL Query em Loops é uma boa prática?

Tags: mysql, sql, desempenho

Montar `query` com `Where` ou outros comandos do sql dentro de loops como `Foreach` é uma boa pratica ou nem um pouco recomendado? Existe um jeito melhor de tratar os dados sem ter que fazer tantas chamadas no banco de dados?

Comment: Depende. Você poderia ser mais claro sobre o que você pretende fazer?

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR**: Não, não é uma boa prática.

Resposta longa:

Como regra geral assuma que é sempre melhor inserir o mínimo possível de *overhead* em qualquer processo que você esteja mapeando.

No caso de várias *queries* sendo executadas dentro de um *loop* você está saturando o banco de dados com requisições.

Guardadas as diferenças de implementação entre os SGBDs, Cada uma tem um custo: A *query* é interpretada, mapeada, tem seu plano de execução avaliado, sua concorrência com outras requisições avaliada, páginas de memória reservadas e índices pesquisados, entre outros processos.

Isso dito, vamos a algumas possibilidades. Vou listar o método que você descreveu primeiro.

Nesta simulação,

- `TABELA1` tem 10 registros
- `TABELA2` tem 100 registros
- Chave estrangeira: `TABELA2`.`T1ID` para `TABELA1`.`ID`
- Existem 10 registros em `TABELA2` para cada registro em `TABELA1`

Caso 1: **Chamadas seriais**

```
-- Primeira pesquisa no banco de dados. Retorna 10 registros.
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA1 T1
-- Loop. Uma chamada para cada linha no retorno da consulta acima:
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 1
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 2
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 3
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 4
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 5
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 6
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 7
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 8
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 9
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 10
-- 11 chamadas são realizadas ao banco de dados.
```

Caso 2: **Concatenação via UNION**

```
 -- Você pode concatenar suas chamadas dentro do loop,
 -- e solicitar uma única chamada.
 -- Primeira pesquisa no banco de dados. Retorna 10 registros.
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA1 T1
 -- Loop e concatenação. Uma chamada contendo o seguinte texto:
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 1 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 2 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 3 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 4 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 5 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 6 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 7 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 8 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 9 UNION
  SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID = 10
-- 2 chamadas são realizadas ao banco de dados.
```

Caso 3: **Cláusula IN**

```
-- Vários SGBDs implementam a cláusula IN:
-- Primeira pesquisa no banco de dados. Retorna 10 registros.
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA1 T1
-- Loop e concatenação em um único parâmetro:
> SELECT ID, NOME FROM TABELA2 T2 WHERE T2.T1ID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
-- 2 chamadas. Muito menos conteúdo a ser interpretado
-- pelo SGDB do que o caso 3.
```

Caso 4a: **SubQuery**

```
> SELECT ID, NOME
  FROM TABELA2 T2
  WHERE T2.T1ID IN
     (
        SELECT ID
        FROM TABELA1 T1
     )
-- Uma única chamada ao banco.
```

Caso 4b: **JOIN**

```
> SELECT ID, NOME 
    FROM TABELA2 T2
    JOIN TABELA1 T1
      ON T2.T1ID = T1.ID
-- Uma única chamada ao banco. Em alguns SGDBs, mais performático do que 4a.
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria testar cada uma dessas opções na aplicação real antes de decidir. Cada caso é um caso, é difícil saber qual é a opção mais performática sem testar.